# Batch File: Is it possible to extract a substring where the index is a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, substring

If I have two variables, `string` and `index`, and I want to extract a substring starting from the index, can I use the `SET` command to do this?  For example:

```
@ECHO off
SET string=Hello
SET index=3
ECHO %string:~%index%%
```

This returns `Helloindex%` when expected result is `lo`.  Is what I am trying to do possible?

Regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET string=Hello
SET index=3
ECHO !string:~%index%!
GOTO :EOF
```

Certainly. Here's one way, using delayedexpansion.

Which method you might use depends on quite what your intentions and parameters are. Your question is really too general for the multitude of solutions and special cases.

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to extract a substring from each line in a file within a FOR loop?  Assuming that each line is read into variable %%a, can I do something like ECHO %%a:~!INDEX!?

Comment: The trick there is to assign the value of `%%a` to a variable, then substring using !vara:~%index%! . simply replace `SET string=Hello` above with `SET "string=%%a"`; parenthesise that `set` with the `echo` as the target of the `for` loop. The setting of `index` can be moved to outside of the `for` loop of course. All depends on the particulars of your application. More info provided ==> better solution.

Answer (score 2):

In case of substringing within **brackets** you can use this - again faster than `CALL` approach but is a little bit verbose (e.g. for loop , if conditions...):

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

echo %str:~2,5%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%start% %end%") do echo !str:~%%a,%%b!
endlocal
```

In case your substring is not extracted within brackets (same as magoo's answer):

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo %str:~2,5%
echo !str:~%start%,%end%!
endlocal
```

another way is to use `CALL` , but this is much slower (despite it requires less code):

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

echo %str:~2,5%
call echo %%str:~%start%,%end%%%
```

It can be done also with a subroutine but as it also uses `CALL` and it's not very performant  way:

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

call :substr "%str%" %start% %end%
goto :eof

:substr
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "_str=%~1"
echo !_str:~%2,%3!
rem without delayedExpansion
rem call echo %%_str:~%2,%3%%
endlocal
goto :eof
```