# Batch File: How can I extract the substring of a value from a FOR loop using an index variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have a text file that I read with a `FOR` loop.  For every line, I want to extract a substring starting from an `INDEX` parameter.  The code I have is as follows:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (cases.txt) DO (
    SET INDEX=3
    SET LINE=%%a

    ECHO !LINE:~!INDEX!!
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The ECHO simply attaches the word "INDEX" at the end of each line.  Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (cases.txt) DO (
    SET INDEX=3
    SET LINE=%%a
    for %%# in (!INDEX!) do echo  !LINE:~%%#!

)
GOTO :EOF
```

As you asked a more broad [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565271/388389) , you can my more broad answer there with more techniques and explanations :-)

What happens to your code?

the parser checks for `!!` and `!line:~!` variables and as they do not exist the only one thing left for echo is `INDEX`. With delayed expansion you cannot use nested variables - you can with [call](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html#Advansed) , but this will harm your performance

Comment: Thank you so much!  Also, your comment on my other post is very useful!